# Virtual Host not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost, opensuse

I'm trying to setup Apache virtual hosting in openSUSE, for a site called `abc.com` (example purposes only). When I go to `http://localhost/mysites/abc.com/index.html` on my browser, it opens correctly. However, when I go to `http://abc.com`, it doesn't open the said index.html file, which is located on `/files/htdocs/mysites/abc.com/index.html`. Instead, it  opens the website of the TV network.

Here is my configuration:

**`default-server.conf`**:

```
DocumentRoot "/files/htdocs"
<Directory "/files/htdocs">
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

Note: I didn't change the other default values.

**`vhost.conf`** inside `vhosts.d/`, included thru `httdp.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
 DocumentRoot /files/htdocs/mysites/abc.com
 servername abc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `abc.com` resolve to an IP address on which your webserver is listening. You appear to have everything on the loopback address `127.0.0.1`. The easiest way to do this is to add `abc.com` to the line in your `/etc/hosts` file that defines localhost.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost abc.com
```

You say

> However, when I go to http://abc.com, it doesn't open the said
>   index.htmlHTML file, which is located on
>   /files/htdocs/mysites/abc.com/index.html. Instead, it opens the
>   website of the TV network.

If you really are using `abc.com` then this would not be a good thing. You'd be much better off using `abc.lan` or `abc.local` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `abc.com` domain to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain    abc.com
```